# Lagrange dual method and KKT condition

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation}\notag
\begin{split}
\max & x^2+y^2 \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & x^2 \leq 1 \\
& 0\leq y\leq 2 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Obviously, the optimal solution should be $x^*=1, y^*=2$ or $x^*=-1,y^*=2$. I am wondering how to use Lagrange dual method and KKT condition to solve it.

It seems that 
$$L(x,y,\lambda)=x^2+y^2-\lambda_1 (x^2-1) - \lambda_2 (y-2) + \lambda_3 y.$$
Due to the KKT condition, the gradient of $L$: $$ [2(1-\lambda_1^*)x^*, 2y^*-\lambda_2^*+\lambda_3^*]=0$$ And also,
$$x^{*2}\leq 1$$
$$0\leq y^*\leq 2$$
$$\lambda_i^*\geq 0$$
$$\lambda_1^*(x^2-1)=0$$
$$\lambda_2^*(y-2)=0$$
$$-\lambda_3^* y=0$$
However, I still couldn't get the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the constraints satisfies LICQ. So you cannot use KKT.

Comment: @Nameless To be precise you need to have some constraint qualification (not necessarily LICQ) in order for KKT to be valid.

Comment: @MIMIGA Why don't you write $x^2\leq 1$ as two linear inequality constraints? You'll be able to apply KKT as you only have linear inequality constraints.

Comment: @S.B. Even though there are still more than two solutions: for example, $ x^*=1, y^*=0, \lambda_1^*=2, \lambda_2^*=0, \lambda_3^*=0, \lambda_4^*=0$.

Comment: @MIMIGA KKT only gives you necessary conditions (if constraint qualifications hold). It's not always sufficient. In general, you have to check the solutions you obtain from KKT conditions for instance by second-order optimality conditions to see if they are local minimum or maximum.

Comment: @S.B. But this problem is convex, KKT should be both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @MIMIGA It's a maximization of a convex function.

Comment: @S.B. That's a stupid mistake. THanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem in standard format \begin{equation}\notag
\begin{split}
\min & -(x^2+y^2) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & (x^2-1) \leq 0 \\
& -y \leq 0 \\
& (y-2) \leq 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
Now the Lagrange Dual will be
\begin{equation}
L(x,y,\lambda)=-x^2-y^2+\lambda_1 (x^2-1) - \lambda_2 y + \lambda_3 (y-2) \hspace{2ex} \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \geq 0 
\end{equation}

Now the necessary conditions are

1. \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} & = 0 \\
   -2x + 2x\lambda_1 & = 0 \\
    2x(\lambda_1-1)& = 0  \\ 
   \end{split}\label{a}\tag{1}
   \end{equation}
2. \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} & = 0 \\
   -2y - \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 & = 0 \\
    y& = \frac{\lambda_3-\lambda_2}{2}  \\ 
   \end{split}\label{b}\tag{2}
   \end{equation}
3. \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   \lambda_1 (x^2-1) = 0 
   \end{split}\label{c}\tag{3}
   \end{equation}

4.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lambda_2 y = 0 
\end{split}\label{d}\tag{4}
\end{equation}

5.
\begin{equation}
\lambda_3 (y-2) = 0 \label{e}\tag{5}
\end{equation}

***case-1:***
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = 0, \lambda_3 = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{b} \implies y = 0 \label{f} \tag{1a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{d} \implies y \neq 0 \label{g} \tag{1b}
\end{equation}

$\ref{f}$ and $\ref{g}$ contradictory. So, both $\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ can not be zero at the same time.

***case-2:***
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = 0, \lambda_3 \gt 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{e} \implies y=2 \label{h} \tag{2a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{b}, \ref{h} \implies \lambda_3 = 4 \label{i} \tag{2b}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{a} \implies x = 0 \label{j} \tag{2c}
\end{equation}

$x=0, y=2 \implies x^2+y^2 = 4$

***case-3:***
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 \gt 0, \lambda_2 = 0, \lambda_3 \gt 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 \gt 0, \ref{c} \implies x^2-1 = 0 \implies x = \pm 1 \label{k} \tag{3a} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{from case-2} \hspace{2ex} \lambda_3 \gt 0, \lambda_2 = 0 \implies y = 2, \lambda_3 = 4 \label{l} \tag{3b} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ref{a}, \ref{k} \implies \lambda_1=1  \label{m} \tag{3c} 
\end{equation}

$x=\pm 1, y=2 \implies x^2+y^2 = 5$